# AngularJS unexpected error

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am working on **angularJS** suddenly I got this error, don't know where and why this has occurred. I think it has occurred in one of the controllers but not so sure why.

> angular-messages.js:294 Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).info
> is not a function at
>
> angular-messages.js:294 at
>
> angular-messages.js:829

Comment: Please add your complete code.

Comment: Make sure that all of your Angular modules are / support the same version

Comment: You have to ensure all AngularJS libraries are using the same versions, it's not supported to combine (for example) 1.4 of ngAnimate with 1.5 of ngRoute

Comment: It may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415827/ngmessages-uncaught-typeerror-l-module-info-is-not-a-function